# Hide button in Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have created a search page on my website that displays result in a listview. Each result has a button and i want to hide that button if the user in the search result is a Friend.

So if the value of status is 1 for any user id, that person is a friend hide the button.

The query to check if the status is 1 works, but the button is still visible. To get the user id of the user, i have used addFriend.CommandArgument. addfriend is the botton.

One of the problems is the searchpage wont load because the variable for addfriend is not found.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {

        if (addFriend == null)
        {
            // IF I REMOVE THIS THE PAGE WILL NOT LOAD BECAUSE PAGE DISPLAYS THE DATA AFTER A BUTTON CLICK ON THE PAGE
        }

        else
        {
            var addFriend = sender as Button;
            // Get the UserId
            Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


            string insertSql = "SELECT Status from User_friend WHERE ((ProfileId1 = @FriendProfileId) AND (ProfileId = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile  WHERE UserId = @UserId))) OR ((ProfileId = @FriendProfileId) AND (ProfileId1 = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile  WHERE UserId = @UserId)))";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", addFriend.CommandArgument);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
                object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();



                if (Convert.ToString(result) == "1")
                {
                    Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("addFriend");
                    hdn.Visible = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i make it work

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio has an excellent debugging tool, something SO isn't able to provide.

Comment: Not sure how you're getting the data you're using to bind to the listview, but you may want to consider bringing the status back with that call rather than making a separate database call for every item in the listview. If you do, you can bind the button's visible property to the value of status. Something like Visible='<%# Eval("Status") %>'. Hopefully, this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, you idea is alot better. I will try it and give u a feed back

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the button invisible, try using JQuery. as the c# property .Visible, makes the button completely invisible to the DOM, and henseforth completely invisible to the page.

By declaring the following at the bottom of the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#<%=addFriend.ClientID %>').hide();
      });
</script>
```

The page will still load because the variable is found, but is hidden. The same can be said if you gave: `<asp:button style="display: none;" />` and then control the button visibility via the DOM

Comment: Thanks, i have thought about j query, but i don't want the button to invisible permanently. i want it to be visible in some conditions